# How to get unique values in a column but adding more columns to my query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with telephone numbers and multiple packets which they belong. Some numbers belong to a single packet and some other to multiple packets. Packets are sort ascending.

I need to get a new table with the numbers and only the first (oldest) packet.

If I use this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Cli_Inyectados.Telefono, Cli_Inyectados.Paquete INTO New_Table
FROM Cli_Inyectados;
```

I will get the same table because there are not duplicate records.

If I use `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCTROW` I get the same result.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  How do you know which row is oldest?

Comment: Packet numbers are composed by a two digits ascending number, the year and the week's number.

Example:

Telefono   134583020
Paquete    39-20.w01

Phone numbers are stored multiple times and so do packets but same combination isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid the correlated subquery if not calculating running aggregations. Instead, consider joining to an aggregate subquery:

```sql
SELECT i.Telefono, i.Paquete
INTO New_Table
FROM Cli_Inyectados i
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT Telefono
         , MIN(Paquete) AS min_Paquete
    FROM Cli_Inyectados
    GROUP BY Telefono
   ) agg
 ON i.Telefono = agg.Telefono
 AND i.Paquete = agg.min_Paquete
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a correlated subquery.  Assuming you have a timestamp column of some sort -- which is arbitrarily called `created_at` in the below query:

```
SELECT i.Telefono, i.Paquete
INTO New_Table
FROM Cli_Inyectados as i
WHERE i.created_at = (SELECT MIN(i2.created_at)
                      FROM Cli_Inyectados as i2
                      WHERE i2.Telefono = i.Telefono
                     );
```

Comment: @yogurblanco . . . Of course.  Otherwise, I would not have provided the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you said but actually I have no more fields than Telefono (number) and Paquete (short text). So I've tried whit this code after checking that MIN for the Paquete field returns the lowest value.

```
SELECT i.Telefono, i.Paquete
INTO New_Table
FROM Cli_Inyectados as i
WHERE i.Paquete = (SELECT MIN(i2.Paquete)
                      FROM Cli_Inyectados as i2
                      WHERE i2.Telefono = i.Telefono
                     );
```

But it takes a lot of time so I think I'm doing it wrong.

Current Cli_Inyectados table has more than 17,000 records but only 3,020 different phone numbers so my New_table must have 3,020 records.